# Java compilation of methods

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand the Java compiler better, and what is happening behind the scenes during compilation and execution, and so I have a question about how Java methods are compiled.

I know that methods need to be called upon or *invoked* in order for their enclosing code to be executed, and I just want to figure out how this really works

Considering the simple program:

```java
public class Test {
    
    public static void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
     public static void main(String []args){
        sayHello();
     }
}
```

Considering that code in java is executed in the order that it appears, why would the contents of sayHello() not be executed, but instead the program waits until the method is invoked for the contents of the method to be executed? So basically I'm asking how does the compiler deal with compiling methods, and what does it do to prevent methods from the contents of a method being run sequentially without them being called on?

Thank you.

Comment: If running a programm or class would lead to all and ever method being executed how would you as a programmer even have any control over what your program does? A huge program can be thousands of classes with methods. How would you expect programming to even work when you as a programmer have no control of when and how those methods are executed? Java has a single entry point with its main method because this is the only way that writing java programs is possible.

Comment: *"Considering that code in java is executed in the order that it appears, ..."* That is not correct.  I think you need a better understanding of the semantics of Java programs before you can hope to understand how the compiler works / what happens "behind the scenes".

Comment: Every working procedure, from a cumbersome chore to a Computer Science process, needs some conventions and rules to work with. The conventions and rules make the processing more flexible (independent on the sequences) and reliable (easy to pinpoint the problems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assertion, "*Considering that code in java is executed in the order that it appears*", was refuted in comments. However, there is one way in which you could say there is some truth to it, as long as you interpret your statement in a specific way. Let's look at your class:

```
public class Test {
```

Here, you're asking the compiler to create a class, and store it in file Test.class.

```
    public static void sayHello() {
```

This tells the compiler to define a method called sayHello.

```
        System.out.println("Hello World");
```

This declares to the compiler that this is the content of the method, and to store this content for execution when the method is called.

```
    }

     public static void main(String []args){

        sayHello();
```

This tells the compiler to call the method `sayHello` whenever the method `main` is called and its body starts getting executed. The method `main` is called when you run the application with the `java` command line.
}
}

You see, in a way the contents are "executed" (for some unusual definition of executed) in the order they appear. But that doesn't mean they are run at that time.

Comment: This is basically what I was looking for in an answer, thank you. So just for clarification the compiler would compile the content of the method, but just store that compiled code until the method is called upon, and then that code is ran?

Comment: yes, that's right

Answer (score 0):

The main() function will almost always be executed first.
It is the function that actually contains the code that is run.
Normally you put main() at the top and other functions below it.